# john the ripper не работает

Tags: utf-8

```
C:\john\run

λ john --session=rar --rules --wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/sqlmap.txt rar.txt
Warning: detected hash type "RAR5", but the string is also recognized as "RAR5-opencl"
Use the "--format=RAR5-opencl" option to force loading these as that type instead
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Loaded 1 password hash (RAR5 [PBKDF2-SHA256 128/128 SSE2 4x])
Cost 1 (iteration count) is 32768 for all loaded hashes
Will run 2 OpenMP threads
fopen: /usr/share/wordlists/sqlmap.txt: No such file or directory

C:\john\run

λ john --show rar.txt
0 password hashes cracked, 1 left

C:\john\run

λ john --format=rar --wordlist=cracked_pass.txt rar.txt
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)
```

Answer (score 0):

сейчас пробую из своего списка паролей методом брута

```
λ john --rules --wordlist=cracked_pass.txt rar.txt
Warning: detected hash type "RAR5", but the string is also recognized as "RAR5-opencl"
Use the "--format=RAR5-opencl" option to force loading these as that type instead
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Loaded 1 password hash (RAR5 [PBKDF2-SHA256 128/128 SSE2 4x])
Cost 1 (iteration count) is 32768 for all loaded hashes
Will run 2 OpenMP threads
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
0g 0:00:00:19 0,00% (ETA: 2020-11-12 03:32) 0g/s 60.55p/s 60.55c/s 60.55C/s flash..lennon
0g 0:00:00:20 0,00% (ETA: 2020-11-12 03:11) 0g/s 60.57p/s 60.57c/s 60.57C/s roscoe..lolita
0g 0:00:00:21 0,00% (ETA: 2020-11-12 02:53) 0g/s 60.60p/s 60.60c/s 60.60C/s unicorn..pegasus
0g 0:00:03:17 0,02% (ETA: 2020-11-14 00:27) 0g/s 52.62p/s 52.62c/s 52.62C/s 10051986..05041983
0g 0:00:03:18 0,02% (ETA: 2020-11-14 00:08) 0g/s 52.67p/s 52.67c/s 52.67C/s things..rapper
0g 0:00:03:19 0,02% (ETA: 2020-11-13 23:49) 0g/s 52.71p/s 52.71c/s 52.71C/s mario66..harriet
```